Unable to install autofs on rhel9
When I try sudo dnf install autofs, I get this error:
[MIRROR] autofs-5.1.7-58.el9.x86_64.rpm: Status code: 403 for https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel9/9/x86_64/baseos/os/Packages/a/autofs-5.1.7-58.el9.x86_64.rpm (IP: 184.51.36.251)
[MIRROR] libsss_autofs-2.8.2-2.el9.x86_64.rpm: Status code: 403 for https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel9/9/x86_64/baseos/os/Packages/l/libsss_autofs-2.8.2-2.el9.x86_64.rpm (IP: 184.51.36.251)
[MIRROR] autofs-5.1.7-58.el9.x86_64.rpm: Status code: 403 for https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel9/9/x86_64/baseos/os/Packages/a/autofs-5.1.7-58.el9.x86_64.rpm (IP: 184.51.36.251)
[MIRROR] libsss_autofs-2.8.2-2.el9.x86_64.rpm: Status code: 403 for https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel9/9/x86_64/baseos/os/Packages/l/libsss_autofs-2.8.2-2.el9.x86_64.rpm (IP: 184.51.36.251)
[FAILED] libsss_autofs-2.8.2-2.el9.x86_64.rpm: No more mirrors to try - All mirrors were already tried without success
(2/2): autofs-5.1.7-  9% [=-                  ] 484 kB/s |  42 kB     00:00 ETA
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: Error downloading packages:
  libsss_autofs-2.8.2-2.el9.x86_64: Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success

I attempted to unregister, register, and then refresh my subscription, but after that, attempting to install autofs just gives me this error which is arguably worse:
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:14:54 ago on Fri 31 May 2024 02:02:08 PM CDT.
No match for argument: autofs
Error: Unable to find a match: autofs

I also tried:
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/9-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/autofs-5.1.6-1.el9.x86_64.rpm

which gave me:
--2024-05-31 14:15:30--  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/9-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/autofs-5.1.6-1.el9.x86_64.rpm
Resolving mirror.centos.org (mirror.centos.org)... 64.150.179.24, 2607:ff28:8005:5:225:90ff:fea8:cd64
Connecting to mirror.centos.org (mirror.centos.org)|64.150.179.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2024-05-31 14:15:31 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Ironically, I successfully installed autofs on another one of my linux servers running under the same subscription yesterday, but installing does not work on another node today.

The machine is getting a 403 error for the Red Hat repos and also can't reach the CentOS repo. Can it reach anything externally other than the subscription server for Red Hat?

Turns out yesterday was the last day of my redhat developer subscription, and I needed to get a new one in order to continue installing packages using dnf. All is well.
